# Query based on a conditional parameter?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I need to run a query that pulls client machine information into PowerBI from SQL Server based on required and non required parameters.

I have the parameters set up but am unable to get my SQL code to work. My two parameters are SelectClient1 and SelectClient2. Some clients have multiple names and usually an acronym abbreviation such as Joe's Construction, Joe's Construction LLC, and JCLLC. I need to be able to bring back all those names.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.InspectionId = table2.InspectionId 
  AND OwnerName like '%"&SelectClient1&"%' 
  OR OwnerName like '%"&SelectClient2&"%'
```

My issue with the code above is sometimes I will leave SelectClient2 blank. In this case I would need the code to work and only bring back where owner is like SelectClient1.

Return something like this...

```
InspectionID  Client                    Machine  Severity
1             "Joe's Construction LLC"  A        High
2             "Joe's Construction LLC"  B        Low
3             "Joe's Construction"      A        Low
4             "JCLLC"                   A        Medium
5             "JCLLC"                   B        Medium
```

Comment: You really should be using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are struggling here because you don't have any parenthesis around your predicates. If you used "modern" join structure this wouldn't matter in your query. Here is what your query would look like using ANSI-92 style joins and parameters. Please note that when you have a leading wildcard in a predicate like this you have rendered the query nonSARGable and no indexing is going to help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
join table2 on table1.InspectionId = table2.InspectionId 
WHERE OwnerName like '%' + @SelectClient1 + '%' 
    OR OwnerName like '%' + @SelectClient2 + '%'
```

Comment: Not sure why this works, but it does... My only concern now is how I apply this when I'm merging more than 2 tables. In some of my queries I am combining 5 or 6 tables. I wouldn't know how to perform those joins other than the ancient way I've been doing

Comment: You simply add more joins. If all you ever do is a comma separated list of tables how do you accommodate left or right joins? The *= and =* syntax has been removed since 2008. The reason this works is because you didn't have parenthesis. You have have left the join in where clause but then you would have needed "where t1.ID = t2.ID AND (Owner Like 'blah' OR Owner like 'bleh')

Comment: I've never needed to perform a left or right join. As you can probably tell from the question, our database management is atrocious, allowing for users to enter whatever they'd like in the fields. All tables I've ever had to join are segments and sub-segments of a header table; thus it has always been necessary to use all observations from both tables

Comment: Yikes that does sound horrible.